# PythonKit/PythonLibrary.swift:46: Fatal error: Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library

Tags: python, ios, swift, swift-pythonkit

Ok I'm fairly new to swift and am trying to create an app with a button that uses python. I have seem code looking like

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Shared
//
//  Created by Ulto4 on 10/17/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import PythonKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showDetails = false
    @State var result : String = " "
   
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            Button(action : {
                self.coolPerson()
            }, label: {
                Text("Respones")
            })
        Text("\(result)")
        
    }
    }
    func coolPerson(){
        let sys = Python.import("sys")
        sys.path.append("/Users/ulto4/Documents/vsc")
        let example = Python.import("ahhhhh")
        let response = example.hi()
        result = response.description
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

The code in the python file is

```py
def hello():
    return "cool"
```

However, when I click the button I get this error

```
2021-10-17 17:53:16.943097-0700 GAAIN[27059:2277939] PythonKit/PythonLibrary.swift:46: Fatal error: Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library.
(lldb)
```

I also clicked the .xcodeproj and deleted the Apple Sandbox. But it still doesn't work. Since I'm fairly new I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  As per the comments, IOS doesn't support PythonKIT

Comment: `PythonKit requires Swift 5 or higher and has been tested on macOS, Linux and Windows.`
no iOS support

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to make a quick change from IOS to macOs in Swift?

Comment: Just create a new MacOS project and copy your code into it